# TargetInvocationException thrown in mvc4 internet default application

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I just made a new `ASP.net MVC4` internet application in `VS2010`. While clicking on **register** or **login**  links, browser throughs an exception(please see below). I did not make a single change in the code. I have new installation of `Vislual Studio Professional 2010`. In previous installation everything was working correct.

Exception is thrown at the line of code

```
LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref     
_initializerLock);
```

and detailed method is here

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Filters
{
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple   
=       false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }

    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

            try
            {
                using (var context = new UsersContext())
                {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())
                    {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity      
Framework migration schema

((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }
```

Detail of exception is

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection  
to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the  
instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote 
connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating 
Server/Instance Specified)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web  
request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and  
where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-
specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was 
not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL 
Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, 
error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you do not have a running SQL database instance. Check the connection string in your web.config and make sure that you have a SQL server installed on the machine specified in this connection string and that this server is accessible.

Comment: I have SQL server management studio in my machine and I can see that the local (dot) is accessible there. Connection string in the web.config is also there,

    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data     
     Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-
     MvcApplication1-20140129135826;Integrated Security=SSPI"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Make sure that you have SQLExpress instance running locally.

Comment: How to check that? Please describe, I am new in web development.

Comment: Do you have Platform SQL Express installed on your machine? Normally this comes with Visual Studio but worth checking out despite that. Look in the installed programs whether you have Microsoft SQL Server on your machine. Also look in the Services whether it is started.